How to turn a downloaded material into a group node?
I'm following along to this Poliigon tutorial on YouTube and the narrator used the poliigon add-on to import a texture from Poliigon and then selected it as a group node. My question is, is there a way to turn a downloaded texture (Like from Polyhaven for example) into a group node? Or at least is there an equivalent that would act in the same way? The picture is what it looks like in the video when he adds the group node of the material. 

Hello and welcome. i'm not sure to understand your questions correctly, but any material node setup that you make can be put into a node group by selecting all the setup and pressing CTRL + G


is there a way to turn a downloaded texture (Like from Polyhaven for example) into a group node

If you mean that in an automated way that works with every texture from anywhere, then no.
Either you import an already made material, or node group, or your library platform provides an addon to generate them for you depending on the resource it gives you.
That being said, something close enough is, whenever you have a set of PBR textures (albedo/base, specular, metallic, normal, etc, which is most of what you would ever see nowadays), and if you have enabled the Node Wrangler addon, you can select your Principled BSDF node, hit ⎈ Ctrl⇧ ShiftT, browse for your texture set, and it will automatically recognize the textures and set them up with your Principled BSDF:

It's all you need to do with a set of PBR textures most of the time (you might want to play with mapping or remaining Principled's properties, but that's all). Putting such things in a node group sounds like a waste of time and resources for nothing.
But for other things, since there are no standards, there can't really be a generic automated way to do things.

When it comes to your example, judging by the inputs it looks more like either a procedural texture (which may or may not use images somewhere in the process) that was then put in a nodegroup for simpler daily usage, or if not procedural it seems to at least have lots of mapping controls which the author deemed very useful for himself and preferred to compile with his textures into a node group, which isn't necessarily something generic that you can apply to any procedural texture, nor that would suit your own preferences and needs. But you could probably look inside, see what it does, and make your own nodegroup which then you can customize and reuse as you want.
If you have a complex set of nodes that you want to turn into a more appealing look and simpler usage, you can select those nodes, hit ⎈ CtrlG to turn them into a node group, then use ↹ Tab to go in and out of the group. The Group's Input and Output nodes allow you to handle which input and output sockets are accessible from outside, which data they carry, to which nodes, ...
Here's an example of a simple node setup i have to convert a smooth gradient into a stepped gradient:

I will never ever need to touch these nodes making the stepping effect, all I need to have access to it the two inputs and the one single output. So the node group allows me to have only these three values exposed, and visually have it all contained in one node, even though from the computing side of things it's more complex than that. And more importantly: it's instantiated, so it is reused as at low cost anywhere you want.
